# Override Ruby class method; can't resolve namespace

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to override [this method](https://github.com/RedisLabs/redis-rb/blob/ssl/lib/redis/connection/ruby.rb#L212-L233), abbreviated here.

```
class Redis
  module Connection
    class Ruby
      include Redis::Connection::CommandHelper

      def self.connect(config)
        if config[:scheme] == "unix"
          sock = UNIXSocket.connect(config[:path], config[:timeout])
        else
          sock = TCPSocket.connect(config[:host], config[:port], config[:timeout])
          if config[:scheme] == "rediss" or config[:use_ssl]
            ssl_context = OpenSSL::SSL::SSLContext.new
            ssl_context.ca_file = config[:ssl_ca_file]
            ssl_context.key = config[:ssl_key]
            ssl_context.cert = config[:ssl_cert]
            ssl_context.verify_mode = config[:ssl_verify_mode]
            ssl_client = OpenSSL::SSL::SSLSocket.new sock, ssl_context
            ssl_client.connect
            sock = ssl_client
          end
        end

        instance = new(sock)
        instance.timeout = config[:timeout]
        instance.set_tcp_keepalive config[:tcp_keepalive]
        instance
      end
    end
  end
end
```

So I've created a RubyGem, that has a runtime dependency on 'redis'. In the gem's lib folder, I have a file with

```
begin
  require "openssl"
rescue LoadError
  #ignore the error, ssl support will not work
end

Redis::Connection::Ruby.class_eval do
  def self.connect(config)
    if config[:scheme] == "unix"
      sock = UNIXSocket.connect(config[:path], config[:timeout])
    else
      sock = TCPSocket.connect(config[:host], config[:port], config[:timeout])
      if config[:scheme] == "rediss" or config[:use_ssl]
        ssl_context = OpenSSL::SSL::SSLContext.new
        ssl_context.ca_file = config[:ssl_ca_file]
        ssl_context.key = config[:ssl_key]
        ssl_context.cert = config[:ssl_cert]
        ssl_context.verify_mode = config[:ssl_verify_mode]
        ssl_client = OpenSSL::SSL::SSLSocket.new sock, ssl_context
        ssl_client.connect
        sock = ssl_client
      end
    end

    instance = new(sock)
    instance.timeout = config[:timeout]
    instance.set_tcp_keepalive config[:tcp_keepalive]
    instance
  end
end
```

Here's the error I get:

```
/vagrant/misinformed/redis-rb-ssl/lib/redis/connection/ruby.rb:7:in `<top (required)>': uninitialized constant Redis::Connection::Ruby (NameError)
    from /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/redis-3.2.1/lib/redis/connection.rb:9:in `require'
    from /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/redis-3.2.1/lib/redis/connection.rb:9:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/redis-3.2.1/lib/redis.rb:2631:in `require'
    from /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/redis-3.2.1/lib/redis.rb:2631:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.7.12/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `require'
    from /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.7.12/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `block (2 levels) in require'
    from /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.7.12/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `each'
    from /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.7.12/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `block in require'
    from /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.7.12/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `each'
    from /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.7.12/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `require'
    from /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.7.12/lib/bundler.rb:134:in `require'
    from /vagrant/dragondoor/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.9/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:146:in `require'
    from /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.9/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:146:in `require_application_and_environment!'
    from /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.9/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:68:in `console'
    from /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.9/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:40:in `run_command!'
    from /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.9/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:8:in `require'
    from bin/rails:8:in `<main>'
```

How can I override that method? My guess is that I either have the namespacing wrong or I need to `require` something, but I haven't been able to get anything to work.

**UPDATED:**

Per a deleted comment, I also tried

```
begin
  require "openssl"
rescue LoadError
  #ignore the error, ssl support will not work
end

class Redis
  module Connection
    Ruby.class_evel do
      def self.connect(config)
        if config[:scheme] == "unix"
          sock = UNIXSocket.connect(config[:path], config[:timeout])
        else
          sock = TCPSocket.connect(config[:host], config[:port], config[:timeout])
          if config[:scheme] == "rediss" or config[:use_ssl]
            ssl_context = OpenSSL::SSL::SSLContext.new
            ssl_context.ca_file = config[:ssl_ca_file]
            ssl_context.key = config[:ssl_key]
            ssl_context.cert = config[:ssl_cert]
            ssl_context.verify_mode = config[:ssl_verify_mode]
            ssl_client = OpenSSL::SSL::SSLSocket.new sock, ssl_context
            ssl_client.connect
            sock = ssl_client
          end
        end

        instance = new(sock)
        instance.timeout = config[:timeout]
        instance.set_tcp_keepalive config[:tcp_keepalive]
        instance
      end
    end
  end
end
```

which seems to have gotten me a little farther, but still getting an error message

```
/home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/app_rails_loader.rb:39: warning: Insecure world writable dir /vagrant/dragondoor in PATH, mode 040777
/home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.7.12/lib/bundler.rb:302: warning: Insecure world writable dir /vagrant/dragondoor in PATH, mode 040777
/vagrant/misinformed/redis-rb-ssl/lib/redis/connection/ruby.rb:9:in `<module:Connection>': uninitialized constant Redis::Connection::Ruby (NameError)
    from /vagrant/misinformed/redis-rb-ssl/lib/redis/connection/ruby.rb:8:in `<class:Redis>'
    from /vagrant/misinformed/redis-rb-ssl/lib/redis/connection/ruby.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/redis-3.2.1/lib/redis/connection.rb:9:in `require'
    from /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/redis-3.2.1/lib/redis/connection.rb:9:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/redis-3.2.1/lib/redis.rb:2631:in `require'
    from /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/redis-3.2.1/lib/redis.rb:2631:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.7.12/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `require'
    from /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.7.12/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `block (2 levels) in require'
    from /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.7.12/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `each'
    from /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.7.12/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `block in require'
    from /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.7.12/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `each'
    from /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.7.12/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `require'
    from /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.7.12/lib/bundler.rb:134:in `require'
    from /vagrant/dragondoor/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.9/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:146:in `require'
    from /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.9/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:146:in `require_application_and_environment!'
    from /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.9/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:68:in `console'
    from /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.9/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:40:in `run_command!'
    from /home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.9/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:8:in `require'
    from bin/rails:8:in `<main>'
```

Comment: did you try to require the file?

Comment: How would I go about requiring the specific file I want to override? The file I want to override is part of another gem. I'm still relatively new at this, so sorry if it's super obvious.

Comment: I did add `require "redis"` and `require "redis/connection/ruby"`, but it didn't do anything different.

Comment: The issue was that I named my directory `lib/redis` which caused some confusion when I entered `require "redis"`. I renamed the directory and the above errors went away. <facepalm />

Comment: LOL - at least you did good and have something great to show off: https://github.com/MisinformedDNA/redis-rb-ssl

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `require 'redis'` to the file where you monkey patch the method:

```
require 'redis'

class Redis
  module Connection
    class Ruby
      def self.connect(config)
        puts 'the method is overriden'
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Well actually, the above initially succeeds without an error, but that is because you are replacing the whole method, instead of just the method.

Comment: don't understand you: 'you are replacing the whole method, instead of just the method'.

Comment: With your code, this `Ruby` class replaces the `Ruby` class that I am trying to override. So instead of a class with many methods, I am left with a class with one method.

So instead of `class Ruby`, I think we want `Ruby.class_eval do` so that we are only replacing the method. Correct me if I'm saying anything wrong.

Comment: No, you're mistaken. In my variant it only overrides one method. See this gist - https://gist.github.com/k-rudy/1f4596fd3029e79b1550 for details. Just run `test.rb` and you'll see what I mean